# Remove random padding from my UL LI?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, padding

I have some sort of space in between my li tags I don't where it's coming from? How can i remove this?

Also, I'd like to change the color of the font to white on hover of the li

JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/omarel/tfyxL66c/

CSS

```
.nav_container {
 text-align: center;
 width:100%;

}
.nav_container ul {
/*  margin-top:15px; */
margin-left:30px;

}
.nav_container ul li {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;  
padding-left:40px;
padding-right:40px;
margin:0px;
height:80px;
cursor:pointer;
}
.nav_container ul li:hover {
background-color:#08298A;
}

.nav_container a:hover {
    color:#fff;
}

header {
width:100%; 
margin: auto;
box-shadow:0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
min-width:410px;
}
.navlogo {
  z-index:99;  
}
.navlogo img {
width:100px;
margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.floatleft {
float:left;    
}
.floatright {
    float:right;    
}
.centerdiv {
 margin:0 auto;   
}
@media only screen and (min-width:700px) {

header {
max-width:1250px;  
}

.container {
    max-width:1250px;   
}

.box2 {

width:32%;
height:300px;
float:left;
}

.box2left {
width:65%;
height:600px;
float:left;
}


}

div {
border:solid 1px #E6E6E6;   
position:relative;
}

ul li {
    border:solid 1px #E6E6E6;  
}
```

HTML

```
        <div class="navlogo floatleft">
           <a href="/"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a>
        </div>

       <div class="floatleft">

          <div class="nav_container">
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
       <div class="floatright">

          <div class="nav_container">
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="">Profile</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Sign out</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>

        </div>


  </header>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your second question first as the answer is shorter: use the `:hover` pseudo class.

**EXAMPLE**

```
li:hover a{color:#fff;}
```

[More information on pseudo classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)

---

To answer your first question, then; setting an element's `display` property to `inline` or `inline-block` will cause the white space surrounding it to be treated just like the space surrounding any other inline element.

You can workaround it in a number of ways

Remove all line breaks from within your list:

```
<ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li></ul>
```

Use comments to hide the line breaks from the browser:

```
<ul><!--
    --><li>Item 1</li><!--
    --><li>Item 2</li><!--
    --><li>Item 3</li><!--
--></ul>
```

Use CSS to set the `font-size` of the parent element to `0` and then "reset" it for the child elements:

```
html{font-size:20px;}
ul{font-size:0;}
li{font-size:1rem;}
```

Alternatively, if you're not 100% set on using `display:inline-block`, you can use floats or flexbox instead.

Comment: This is great, but I'm curious why padding:0 or margin:0 won't prevent that? Does that happen with all inline elements.

Comment: Because it's neither padding nor a margin. To illustrate it what's going on, change the `ul` to a `p` and the `li`s to `span`s. This is the exact same behaviour you have when setting elements, which are otherwise block elements, to `display` as `inline` or `inline-block`

Comment: I've updated this to correctly answer your second question. You asked how to change the colour of the `a` when hovering over the `li`, my original answer only changed the colour when hovering over the `a`.

Answer (score 1):

To change the color of the links to white, use this css:

```
.nav_container ul li:hover a {
    color:white;
}
```

However, only the text will be clickable, the li element won't be clickable. Another way to do the same thing is to apply all width/height/background styling to the link, instead of the li.

Comment: The div that the list is nested in should also be included in order to avoid other potential links in a list on the same page changing colors as well.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that this doesn't seem like good usability. I will try the same with the link

Answer (score 0):

As Shaggy mentioned, to eliminate extra spacing when using `inline-block` you should remove all spaces in your html between your menu `li` items.

As for changing the link color on hover you should add the following to your css code:

```
.nav_container li:hover a {
color:#FFF;
}
```